# detecting bot in asp.net

Tags: security

I have an application where any request on a page must be inserted to a count table , however how can i check if the requesting is a real user not some tool made by a user to make 1 million request in a second or something like this in asp.net ?
note : I cannot put a captcha or something like this on this because the user is not entering any data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a cookie is out of the question then i would suggest time tracking on the server. I would assume you have some way of tracking the user, wehther it be cookie based or by authentication (they logged in to your site). (Without tracking the user it would be pointless counting requests).

This means that for each request from each user, you track two things:

- the user ID
- the time when they requested the page

When they make the request, you increment the counter. If they make another request, you check the timestamp for the previous request - if it is too soon you don't count the current request. This mechanism can be very easily modified to count requests only once every *x* seconds, or even to only count 1 request per day, etc. If you settle on a timespan that would represent continual requests from a normal user, you can skip counting any requests that happen before that timespan has elapsed. Alternatively you could also log those suspect requests. If you are sending data of some sort back with each request, you can send nothing back for the suspect ones.

Comment: No I do not have user id , for example does youtube in their video counters consider the user id or no ?? I dont think so..so even if i recorded the timestamp I dont have the user id .

Comment: @user - at the very least, the user ID could be the IP the request originates from. This is still a little crude (several people could be behind a single IP), but it gives you a way to track the source of a request, and the requester has to go to a bit more trouble to disguise/hide the IP address.

Answer (score 2):

I guess most pages do this via a cookie or they store the IP adress of the requester. The agent can be faked and there a quite a lot of tools around that do this.

hth

Mario

Comment: but sometimes bunch of users share the ip addres...like a company or something all its internal users will be using the same ip address.

Comment: true, then you could use a cookie or user login - see also: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_visitor or http://www.opentracker.net/article/hits-or-pageviews

Answer (score 0):

You can check the user-agent and see if the request is coming from a web browser.

See [this article](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020150659/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/120402-1.aspx) for more info.

Comment: The UserAgent cannot be trusted, it can be anything the requesting agent wants it to be.